# Could anyone tell what's the font used in picture?

Tags: fonts

Could anyone tell what's the font used in the picture below?
[image]

Comment: Where did you find the font?  Where was the image you've uploaded taken from, and is this the highest quality available?  I've tried uploading your image [link](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), but it couldn't find a match, possibly because the image is very low resolution.  If you can get a higher resolution image you might be able to try again.

Comment: I've taken the piece from this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m832u0t3oa6ey9/hockey2014WO.jpeg
Actually, WhatTheFont service couldn\t recognize this font properly. That's why I asked about it there.

Comment: the [graphic design stackexchange site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) has a "font-identification" category.  you can probably receive some help there.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, I'm going to use this option.